# How can this jQuery search filter function be rewritten in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

How could this jQuery search filter function be rewritten in pure JavaScript? The function looks at all li elements whose parent ul element has the category class and hides/shows them based on their content matching or not matching the input from a field with the search class.

```
$(function(){
  $('.search').keyup(function(){
    var searchText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $allListElements = $('ul.category > li'),
    $matchingListElements = $allListElements.filter(function(i, el){
      return $(el).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
    });
    $allListElements.hide();
    $matchingListElements.show();
  });
});
```

EDIT: I tried the function below, but it only targets the first element with the name class inside of the li element, and won't work on the li element as a whole.

```
var input = document.getElementById('search');
input.onkeyup = function () {
  var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    var name = lis[i].getElementsByClassName('name')[0].innerHTML;
    if (name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) == 0) 
        lis[i].style.display = 'list-item';
    else
        lis[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to show us what you've tried and why you think it doesn't work.

Comment: I've checked your code as is on a simple html page, and it seems to be ok (at least in Chrome). See html I used in my answer. Why do you think it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code as is on a simple html page, and it seems to be ok (at least in Chrome):

```
<html>
<body>
<input id="search"/>
<ul class="filter">
    <li><span class="name">filter</span></li>
    <li><span class="name">fi2lter</span></li>
    <li><span class="name">filter</span></li>
    <li><span class="name">filt3er</span></li>
    <li><span class="name">filter</span></li>
</ul>

<script>
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('keyup', function () {
  var filterText = this.value.toLowerCase(),
  lis = document.querySelectorAll('.filter li'),
  i;
  for (i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    if (filterText === '' || getText(lis[i]).toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText) > -1) {
      lis[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
      lis[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
});

getText = function( elem ) {
    var node,
        ret = "",
        i = 0,
        nodeType = elem.nodeType;

    if ( !nodeType ) {
        // If no nodeType, this is expected to be an array
        while ( (node = elem[i++]) ) {
            // Do not traverse comment nodes
            ret += getText( node );
        }
    } else if ( nodeType === 1 || nodeType === 9 || nodeType === 11 ) {
        // Use textContent for elements
        // innerText usage removed for consistency of new lines (jQuery #11153)
        if ( typeof elem.textContent === "string" ) {
            return elem.textContent;
        } else {
            // Traverse its children
            for ( elem = elem.firstChild; elem; elem = elem.nextSibling ) {
                ret += getText( elem );
            }
        }
    } else if ( nodeType === 3 || nodeType === 4 ) {
        return elem.nodeValue;
    }
    // Do not include comment or processing instruction nodes

    return ret;
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I commented on Anton L's answer (thank you again for your help Anton), I was looking for JavaScript that's functionally identical to the jQuery code I provided. There weren't many examples of filtering in pure JavaScript, but I did find a lot of examples in jQuery, so I'm posting my solution as an answer here in case someone else finds it helpful.

HTML:

```
<input id="search"/>
<ul class="filter">
  <li>FIlter</li>
  <li>fi2lter</li>
  <li>filter</li>
  <li>filt3er</li>
  <li>filter</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('keyup', function () {
  var filterText = this.value.toLowerCase(),
  lis = document.querySelectorAll('.filter li'),
  i;
  for (i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    if (filterText === '' || lis[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText) > -1) {
      lis[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
      lis[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Actually this solution has 1 difference comparing to jQuery in case there is some html inside "li" element. If you consider my example below where there is a "span" inside an li element, than none of the li elements will be filtered out in case search field has "spa" text. Please see my example updated to solve this issue.